# What is the underlying language of testRigor?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, testrigor

When the test steps are written, how the steps handled internally ?

I am new to testRigor and trying to understand the internal implementation of testRigor execution.

I understand testRigor is meant to minimise coding for automated tests, but I am eager to understand the internal implementation of testRigor.

Answer (score 0):

TestRigor uses OpenAI GPT, according to the founder Artem Golubev.

The AI was trained to emulate human-like interaction with mobile and web applications using machine learning. Creating tests involves writing AI prompts.

Source: https://club.ministryoftesting.com/t/openai-contains-tools-that-can-help-us-with-test-automation/66881/2